# Linear transformation and linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ bwe a linear transformation. Let $L \subset V$ be a linear subspace such that $L \cap \text{Ker}\,(T)=\{0 \}$.
>
> Prove that the image given by T of any linear independent sequence in L is linear independent sequence.

Actually, I didn't understand the question.

Please help (with understanding the question and solution), thank you!

Comment: I assume your vector space has finite dimension.
You are asked what happens, when you have $k$ linear independent vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_k$, i.e. $\sum\limits{i=1,k}\lambda_iv_i=0$ only if $\lambda_i=0$ for all i, and then take a look at their images under T. There you have to show that their images are linear independent as well. Hint: Since $L \cap Ker(T)=\{0\}$, $T$ confined to $L$ is injective.

Comment: Wait, your math above says $L \cap Ker(T)=\{\theta \}$. With theta do you mean zero or some arbitrary vector called theta??

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contrary, i.e., that for $w_1,\ldots,w_k\in L$ which are linearly independent, their images $Tw_1,\ldots,Tw_k$ are linearly dependent, which means that there exist $c_1,\ldots,c_k$, not all zero, such that
$$
0=c_1Tw_1+\cdots+c_kTw_k=T(c_1w_1+\cdots+c_1w_k).
$$
But this implies that
$$
c_1w_1+\cdots+c_1w_k \in\mathrm{ker}\,T,
$$
and as
$$
c_1w_1+\cdots+c_1w_k \in L,
$$ 
then
$$
c_1w_1+\cdots+c_1w_k \in L\cap\mathrm{ker}\,T=\{0\},
$$
and hence 
$$
c_1w_1+\cdots+c_1w_k=0.
$$
But since $w_1,\ldots, w_k$ are linearly independent, then $c_1=\cdots=c_k=0$, which is a contradiction.